# Perfect, swift, getting server address from request in handler

Tags: swift, perfect

In request handler, processing e.g. `GET` https://example.com/collections/1 or POST`http://0.0.0.0:8080/collections` how do I get server address https://example.com and http://0.0.0.0:8080 respectively?

Currently I'm constructing it like so

```
 var url = "\(httpPrefix)\(server.serverAddress)"
 if server.serverPort != 443 { url += ":\(server.serverPort)" }
```

where `httpPrefix` is:

```
let httpPrefix = isLinux ? "https://" : "http://"
```

But it feels like there's a better way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that `host` header would contain either `example.com` or `0.0.0.0:8080` depending on the server.

So the following produces just the result I need. `httpScheme` is still hardcoded (which is something I don't like, but don't see other options yet).

```
httpScheme + request.header(.host)!
```

I'm force-unwrapping, as I observe host header is always there.